# Execute multiple sql delete query in mysql for php

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason, i want to delete some of records in my table using php mysql query function. Here's what i've write

```
$sql = "delete from progress where first_date='2010-01-01' and last_date='2010-01-31';
delete from progress where first_date='2010-02-01' and last_date='2010-02-28';
delete from progress where first_date='2010-03-01' and last_date='2010-02-31';
delete from progress where first_date='2010-04-01' and last_date='2010-02-30';
delete from progress where first_date='2010-05-01' and last_date='2010-02-31';";

if(!mysql_query($sql)) echo "Error deleting records";
```

Thats exactly what i get, "Error deleting records". However when itrace it using mysql_error() , its no use after all. Anyone know how to handle this? Thank's before

Comment: Change your final echo there to `echo 'Error deleting records: ', mysql_error();`, which will spit out the exact error that occured. Just saying "something happened" is of no use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mysql_query() can't execute multiple statements for security reasons.

use mysqli_multi_query() or call mysql_query() many times.

Comment: yes i did using mysqli_multi_query but once i got error : 'command out of sync, you can't command now' or smiliar

Answer (score 3):

You cannot send more than one SQL query at a time when using `mysql_query()`. That is why it's failing and returning false.

Comment: that's what i've tought before. It's strange beacuse when i use phpmyadmin everithing looks fine

Comment: I think it's because phpMyAdmin parses your SQL, splits statements by the given delimiter and runs `mysql_query()` once for each separate statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can either create different variables for each query and then call the `mysql_query` for each variable created. 
i did it this way when i wanted to execute two queries to select and update at once.

Answer (score 0):

Why not combine all queries into one?

$sql = "DELETE FROM progress WHERE (first_date='2010-01-01' AND last_date='2010-01-31') OR (first_date='2010-02-01' AND last_date='2010-02-28') OR (first_date='2010-03-01' AND last_date='2010-02-31') OR (first_date='2010-04-01' AND last_date='2010-02-30') OR (first_date='2010-05-01' AND last_date='2010-02-31')";

Comment: I will use PDO nowadays, not mysql_query. But your code might worked back then.